# Android Studio run old version

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app using Android Studio.

I had the same issue with a version prior to that.

The problem is that after I changed my code and resource files, I still get the old apk installed on the device or emulator.

What do I need to do to get it to run current code? Is it a building config?

Is it a known issue with Android Studio?

Comment: _What do I need to do to get it to run current code?_ run the project everytime after you made the change or instant run.

Comment: There is no issue with Android Studio in this regard. Be more clear of what you did (may be with some pics).

Comment: @SrikarReddy  I changed the place of the button and deleted textview